# Is there any (good) reason to set/use a custom DNS?

Tags: networking, dns, internet

I came across https://1.1.1.1/, a DNS provider and on their site they tell me I should change my settings so my computer uses their services. Is that just marketing, or are there some real reasons to use a custom DNS?

As far as I've understood (from [multiple](https://superuser.com/questions/610583/is-there-a-reason-to-not-use-googles-dns-servers) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/332448/which-place-do-i-set-up-dns-servers) and answers on this site and my own knowledge) my current DNS is being provided by my ISP. I'm a regular internet user, (watching video's, online gaming) and I'm not having any problems with the current settings, so I was wondering if there are serious good reasons for a user to set a custom DNS?

- Could it indeed (noticeably) improve my speed?
- The site of 1.1.1.1 also says they
  won't store which sites I visit, which other DNS might do to show the right ads to me. As someone who doesn't like personalised ads, is my DNS a thread for me?
- Are there any other benefits of using a custom DNS for my
  computer?
- Are there any downsides I should know about of using a
  custom DNS for my computer?

I did find some tech-news sites that discussed the mater and they all seem to favourite the custom DNS (for speed and privacy), but I'm still wondering how significant these benefits are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you researched so far is potentially correct.

A third party DNS can be faster than your ISP's DNS.  However, speed is relative.  When speed is measured in hundredths or thousandths of a second, you might not notice the difference.

While a third party DNS might not record your DNS and respect your privacy. that doesnt mean your ISP does not see the requests.  Nor does it stop your web browser or the websites you visit from tracking you.

Comment: Are there any other up- or downsides or possible complications that could be caused by setting up my PC to use a custom DNS?

Comment: @Bassie-c not really. It comes down to speed and privacy. How much more or less you get can only be determined by you.

Answer (score 0):

DNS can be used to help Target adds, and I have little doubt that Google's 8.8.8.8 nameserver does just that. 1.1.1.1 is quite new and run by a credible company.

I'm not advicatong using it, but

- sometimes machines/configs/images which move from place will benefit from an off-site nameserver, and an ISPs nameserver will likely reject recursive queries from other providers.
- Also an ISP may be bound by law to block certain content - one way they may do this is by controlling DNS lookups against their nameservers. I doubt it will work anymore but people used to bypass Netflix region restrictions by using DNS.
- 1.1.1.1 is not actually a DNS server, rather it is a geographically distributed system that is part of a large content delivery network, so it may be better at sourcing local/closer copies if data.

Note that none if these things is particularly secure.

Comment: Could you expand on the security part? Why is that the case, because almost all DNS traffic is transmitted unencrypted?

Comment: @Bassie-c yes, it is easy to view and modify DNS traffic as it's unencrypted.

Comment: They also have an android app....https://www.zdnet.com/article/cloudflare-launches-android-and-ios-apps-for-its-1-1-1-1-service/